Cannot reproduce the effect of mallopt(M_PERTURB, 256) with MALLOC_PERTURB_=256
I am looking for a way to pad unitialized double to nan using MALLOC_PERTURB_.
Doing so, I have noticed a difference between mallopt and MALLOC_PERTURB_, when set to 256. They should be equivalent according to the doc.
Consider the following code, where if I export MY_MALLOC_PERTURB_ it calls mallopt:
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>


void print_uninitialized_memory(){
  char* mperturb = getenv("MY_MALLOC_PERTURB_");
  if (mperturb) {
    mallopt(M_PERTURB, atoi(mperturb));
  }

  int* i = new int;
  long* l = new long;
  float* f = new float;
  double* d = new double;
  void** p = new void*;

  std::cout << "with PERTURB = " << (mperturb? mperturb:"unset") << std::endl;
  std::cout << "  undefined int: '" << *i << "'" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "  undefined long: '" << *l << "'" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "  undefined float: '" << *f << "'" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "  undefined double: '" << *d << "'" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "  undefined pointer: '" << *p << "'" << std::endl;
}


int main() {
  print_uninitialized_memory();
  return 0;
}

Using any value 0..255, both mallopt and MALLOC_PERTURB_ set the allocated memory with the same values:
$ MY_MALLOC_PERTURB_=2 ./a.out
with PERTURB = unset
  undefined int: '-33686019'
  undefined long: '-144680345676153347'
  undefined float: '-4.22017e+37'
  undefined double: '-7.84591e+298'
  undefined pointer: '0xfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfd'
$ MALLOC_PERTURB_=2 ./a.out
with PERTURB = 2
  undefined int: '-33686019'
  undefined long: '-144680345676153347'
  undefined float: '-4.22017e+37'
  undefined double: '-7.84591e+298'
  undefined pointer: '0xfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfd'

But for 256:
$ MY_MALLOC_PERTURB_=256 ./a.out
with PERTURB = 256
  undefined int: '-1'
  undefined long: '-1'
  undefined float: '-nan'
  undefined double: '-nan'
  undefined pointer: '0xffffffffffffffff'
$ MALLOC_PERTURB_=256 ./a.out
with PERTURB = unset
  undefined int: '0'
  undefined long: '0'
  undefined float: '0'
  undefined double: '0'
  undefined pointer: '0'

Is it possible to initialize doubles to -nan using the env variable MALLOC_PERTURB_?
If relevant, this was tested with glibc-2.28 and 2.35.

I don't know why that happens, but MY_MALLOC_PERTURB_ seems to be correct according to documentation, it sets ~0 on allocated uninitialised memory. MALLOC_PERTURB_ should do the same thing...

From this doc https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Tunables.html, it seems that the environment variable has a hard-coded max=255:
$ /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --list-tunables
...
glibc.malloc.perturb: 0 (min: 0, max: 255)

This max value is enforced somewhere in glibc (probably in dl-tunables.c and dl-tunables.list:42).
This would also explain why the value 257 behaves as 255 for MALLOC_PERTURB_ and as 1 for mallopt.
